# OpenMP, parallel for loop, bigIntegers

Tags: c++, openmp

Is it possible to make a parallel for loop whose index is not integer?
I use bigIntegers (new object).

Comment: Only built-in integer types and random-access iterators can be used as loop variables.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenMP 4.0 specification was [finalised and published](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/) one year ago. It mandates that variable of parallel loops should be of signed or unsigned integer type or of a random access iterator type or pointer type (§2.6, p.51).

So, basically no, it is not possible to make parallel for-loops with any variable type.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the scheduling yourself.  Here is an example using the equivalent of `schedule(static)` with GCC's builtin 128-bit integers.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    __int128 start = omp_get_thread_num()*N/omp_get_num_threads();
    __int128 finish = (omp_get_thread_num()+1)*N/omp_get_num_threads();
    for(__int128 i=start; i<finish; i++) foo(i);
}
```

If you want the equivalent of `schedule(dynamic)` you can do

```
__int128 cnt = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
for(__int128 i=0;;) {
    #pragma omp atomic capture
    i = cnt++;
    if(i>=N) break;
    foo(i);                                    
}
```